# Splitting the Expression statements with Roslyn

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

I am working in developing an application that rephrases `CSharp` code. I am doing this with `Roslyn`. I am facing a problem with `splitting expressions`.

Sample class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float floatVariable = 20;
        Int16 intVariable = 10;
        string str = "School";
        Console.Write(str + floatVariable.ToString() + intVariable.ToString()); // Facing problem with this statement
    }
}
```

Sample code I am using

```
string code = new StreamReader(classPath).ReadToEnd();
var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
var syntaxRoot = syntaxTree.GetRoot();

//This will get the method and local variables declared inside the method
var MyMethods = syntaxRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
foreach (MethodDeclarationSyntax mds in MyMethods)
{
    syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(mds.ToFullString());
    IEnumerable<SyntaxNode> nodes = syntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes();
    IEnumerable<VariableDeclarationSyntax> variableDeclarations =       nodes.OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>();
    foreach (VariableDeclarationSyntax variable in variableDeclarations)
    {
    // I will collect the variable details like Datatype, variable names and initialized values  here
    }


    foreach (StatementSyntax statement in mds.Body.Statements)
    {
        if (statement.CSharpKind() == SyntaxKind.ExpressionStatement)
        {
            //I want to split the expressions "Console.Write(str + floatVariable.ToString() + intVariable.ToString());" as below

            //1. intVariable.ToString()
            //2. floatVariable.ToString()
            //3. str

            //Then I have to find the whole data type from the resolved result of above 3 => string here            
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

***Edit:***
I am having trouble in splitting the parameterized expression statements. I am trying to do this by,

```
if (statement.CSharpKind() == SyntaxKind.ExpressionStatement)
{
    ExpressionStatementSyntax expression = statement as ExpressionStatementSyntax;
    var expressions = expression.Expression.DescendantNodes();
}
```

But this splits each and every token as a seperate elements. I just want to split the **`Console.Write(str + floatVariable.ToString() + intVariable.ToString())`** into,

1. Console.Write()
2. str
3. intVariable.ToString()
4. floatVariable.ToString()

Comment: The [Roslyn Syntax Tree Visualiser](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/70e184da-9b3a-402f-b210-d62a898e2887) might help you here.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Getting the parameter expression from the statement? Working with binary expressions for `+`? What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: @svick : I have edited the question. Please find it in the **Edit** block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell what exactly do you want to do, because you specified what the code should do only in one specific case, not in general.

The way I interpret it is:

1. For invocation expression, return the expression that's being invoked and also descend into its arguments, if any.
2. For binary operators, descend into both children.
3. For all other expressions, return the expression directly.

With this specification and using `CSharpSyntaxVisitor`, the code could look like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<ExpressionSyntax> Split(ExpressionSyntax expression)
{
    return new SplitVisitor().Visit(expression);
}

class SplitVisitor : CSharpSyntaxVisitor<IEnumerable<ExpressionSyntax>>
{
    public override IEnumerable<ExpressionSyntax> VisitInvocationExpression(
        InvocationExpressionSyntax node)
    {
        yield return node.Expression;

        var argumentExpressions = node.ArgumentList.Arguments
            .SelectMany(a => Visit(a.Expression));
        foreach (var expression in argumentExpressions)
            yield return expression;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ExpressionSyntax> VisitBinaryExpression(
        BinaryExpressionSyntax node)
    {
        foreach (var expression in Visit(node.Left))
            yield return expression;
        foreach (var expression in Visit(node.Right))
            yield return expression;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ExpressionSyntax> DefaultVisit(SyntaxNode node)
    {
        var expression = node as ExpressionSyntax;
        if (expression != null)
            yield return expression;
    }
}
```

Comment: You understood the question correctly and your answer worked as expected. Thanks a lot...

Comment: But the solution is not working for statment `Console.Write(str + string.Concat("str1","str2"))` . The **split** method does not manage the  nested aruments `("str1","str2")` in `string.Concat("str1","str2"));`
[Please find the image for this here](http://imgur.com/fW5Hkc1)

Comment: @MeikandaNayanar.I I don't understand, your image shows that my `Split()` did split the nested `string.Concat("str1","str2")` into `string.Concat`, `"str1"` and `"str2"`. Are you saying that it shouldn't? If that's the case, then I don't understand the rules you want `Split()` to follow.

Comment: I want the Split() method to split the `Console.Write(str + string.Concat("str1","str2"))` to `Console.Write()` , `str` and `string.Concat("str1","str2")`. So that I can further traverse the `string.Concat("str1","str2")` with this **Split()** . Also I need to do the same for the DeclarationExpressions like `Int16 x = Int16.Parse(str)`

Comment: I have added a seperate question for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207650/splitting-the-expressions-with-roslyn . Is this possible.