# Splitting the expressions with Roslyn

Tags: c#, visual-studio, expression-trees, roslyn

I am using Roslyn and I want to split the statement as below,

```
string stringVariable = "string";
int intVariable = 10;
Console.Write(stringVariable + string.Concat("string1","string2") + intVariable.ToString())
```

1. `Console.Write()`
2. `stringVariable`
3. `string.Concat("string1","string2")`
4. `intVariable.ToString()`

I have asked a question and got answer for splitting the expressions [Splitting the Expression statements with Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860876/splitting-the-expression-statements-with-roslyn) but this suggestion splits the `string.Concat("string1", "string2")` as below,

1. `string.Concat()`
2. `string1`
3. `string2`

But i dont want to split the inner expressions, I need to keep the inner expressions as it is. How can I do this with Roslyn?

Comment: I do not likes to split the binary expression with the operator token "+" because if we split the expression with "+" then the result will be in `string` . I need the seperated arguments in expression format like LiteralStringExpression and InvocationExpressions and so on.

Comment: Your question is more complicated than it sounds.  How do you define "inner" expression? What about an expression in a nested lambda?

Comment: @SLaks : Yes, you persumed the question in correct way. i am having trouble in identifying the inner expressions in a complex nested expression. So far I have no idea about how I am going to react with lambda expressions. But I suppose traversing through the descended nodes can do this - Now trying in this way..

Comment: First, you need to decide exactly what you want.  Depending on what you want (for every possible combination of nesting), you can accomplish it by visiting the child nodes with a different visitor, returning them directly, or maintaining a stack of states.

Comment: @SLaks : Yes, but visiting the child nodes just splits the "inner" expressions. That is what this question is all about. This is a binary expression and splitting it by **Visiting** the Right and Left nodes of the expression splits the expression `string.Concat("string1","string2")` into pieces. ***My question is how to recognize these "inner" expression while visiting child nodes?*** . I am using the code in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860876/splitting-the-expression-statements-with-roslyn) to visit the binary expression. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

The expression `Console.Write(stringVariable + string.Concat("string1","string2") + intVariable.ToString())` is a `InvocationExpressionSyntax`. The InvocationExpressionSyntax can be further splitted into **expression** and **arguments**.

Here the expression part will have `Console.Write` and 
the argument part will have `stringVariable + string.Concat("string1","string2") + intVariable.ToString()` .

Now the argument will be the `BinaryExpressionSyntax` .

We can split the BinaryExpressionSyntax by visiting the `SyntaxNodes`. So when Visiting we can just avoid traversing the "inner expressions" by identifyning its 
syntax( like `InvocationExpressionSyntax`, `MemberAccessExpressionSyntax`..etc) .

The code for visiting the Binary expression as above will be.

```
public class BinaryExpressionVisitor : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    List<string> restrictedTokens = new List<string>();
    internal List<object> binaryExpressionNodes = new List<object>();

    public BinaryExpressionVisitor()
    {
        restrictedTokens.Add("IdentifierToken");
        restrictedTokens.Add("NumericLiteralToken");
        restrictedTokens.Add("StringLiteralToken");
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitBinaryExpression(BinaryExpressionSyntax node)
    {
        return base.VisitBinaryExpression(node);
    }

    public override SyntaxNode Visit(SyntaxNode node)
    {
        if (node.GetType().Name != "BinaryExpressionSyntax" && node.GetType().Name != "ParenthesizedExpressionSyntax")
            binaryExpressionNodes.Add(node);
        return base.Visit(node);
    }

    public override SyntaxToken VisitToken(SyntaxToken token)
    {
        if (!restrictedTokens.Contains(token.CSharpKind().ToString().Trim()))
            binaryExpressionNodes.Add(token);
        SyntaxToken baseToken = base.VisitToken(token);
        return baseToken;
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitInvocationExpression(InvocationExpressionSyntax node)
    {
        return node;//Bypassing the expression instead of base.Visit(node)
    }

    public override SyntaxToken VisitListSeparator(SyntaxToken separator)
    {
        SyntaxToken baseToken = base.VisitListSeparator(separator);
        return baseToken;
    }
}
```

The class can be invoked by,

```
BinaryExpressionVisitor expressionVisitor = new BinaryExpressionVisitor();
expressionVisitor.VisitBinaryExpression(binaryExpressions);
List<object> nodeList = expressionVisitor.binaryExpressionNodes;
```

The **nodeList** will have the below result.

- [0] = "IdentifierNameSyntax IdentifierName stringVariable"
- [1] = "SyntaxToken PlusToken +"
- [2] = "InvocationExpressionSyntax InvocationExpression
  string.Concat(\"string1\", \"string2\")"
- [3] = "SyntaxToken PlusToken +"
- [4] = "InvocationExpressionSyntax InvocationExpression
  intVariable.ToString()"